# Cannot read property error in Angular ngrx app

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm trying to create my first angular/rxjs app and  can't figure out why I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'students' of undefined
```

I was trying to follow tutorial but I didn't copy it word by word.
I'm totally new to this.

https://dpaste.de/F415#L1,30,98,131

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I think you missed the init on line 19.  students$: Observable<Student[]> = [];

Comment: i dont think thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

in your init function you have the following:

```
this.students$ = this.store.select(fromStore.getAllStudents);
```

now, this getAllStudents states as follow:

```
export const getAllStudents = createSelector(getStudentState, fromStudents.getStudents);
```

which means we are going to get something from getStudentState first, pass it to the fromStudents.getStudents, and return its returned value.
Let's see what the getStudendState function does:

```
export const getStudentState = createSelector(getState, (state: StudentsState) => state.students);
```

ok, again we take the state from the getState function and return the students property, let's analyze this getState:

```
export const getState = createFeatureSelector<StudentsState>('student-list');
```

Everything is clear now, we get the student-list property and we can travel back to our chain... unless...

```
export interface StudentsState {
  students: fromStudents.StudentState;
}
```

as expected, when we get the *student-list* property from our state, it returns undefined since doesn't exist, and at that point, the getState will try to access *state.students* which will lead to the error you get.

Comment: I changed to: export const getState = createFeatureSelector<StudentsState>('students');

Comment: ^ cant figure it out without you :P

Comment: i can see where your confusion comes from.
Here's my suggestion: change your StudendState interface name to AppState (the one used for the createFeatureSelector, and provide the 'students' string as declared on line 140.
Essentially, you should consider your app state a container for various states. In your case you have just one, but you are using the same name for both.